# How do I send a Federation Proposal to GitBlit mirror?

Tags: federation, gitblit

I was able to stand up our `GitBlit 1.8.0` server with Federation enabled and it is generating the 3 tokens during startup, however, when logging into the server as Admin, it does not show the Federation link (as per the [documentation](http://gitblit.com/federation.html)) in the navigation menu to visit the Federation page for sending a proposal to the mirroring GitBlit server.  Google images shows that the link was present in the 1.6.x version but it's not here in the 1.8.0 version.  I also looked in the Admin user context menu but there is nothing mentioning Federation.

Where is the link to the Federation page to send a proposal?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  As per the documentation, the `gitblit.properties` must include the `git.enableGitServlet=true` and `federation.passphrase=<simplepassword>` to enable the Federation feature in the origin server.  The origin GitBlit server needs to **also contain** the following property *to display the Federation link on the Admin context menu*:

```
web.showFederationRegistrations=true
```

Without this property, Federation may be enabled but the link to the Federation page to issue proposals and view the various server configuration settings available for federating will not appear on the main page.  The origin server must be restarted for the property changes to take effect.

Comment: According to the 1.8.0 release version of `com.gitblit.wicket.pages.RootPage.java`, the Federation menu item is not on the navigation menu but now located in the Admin user menu.  The documentation is out of date as well as the screenshots (http://gitblit.com/screenshots.html).